# How should I include a js file from another js file?

Tags: javascript, reference

What is the best way to add a reference to a javascript file from another javascript file?

Suppose that I have a js file included in my webpage. This javascript has a dependency on another file. So I want to reference the dependency within my js file, and not from the html code. Is my thinking correct?

I know I can create a `script` DOM element and then append it to the page, but that smells bad for me.

Have you any tips about that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Creating a `script` DOM element is the only available way as far as I know. After checking the source code of jQuery and YUI, I couldn't find a better way. Both use this technique. Check out the [globalEval function](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js) in jQuery, and the _[scriptNode function](http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.7.0/build/yuiloader/yuiloader.js) in YUI.

Comment: what about dealing with already loaded scripts ? Is there a simple pattern for `if(!Isloaded("otherscript.js")) { document.write(myscriptdeclaration);} ` ?

Answer (score 4):

```
document.write( '<script language="javascript" src="myotherscript.js" />' );
```

Comment: In my opinion, "document.write" is very inelegant.

Comment: Why? It's universally accepted and easy to use. There's no language equivalent.

Comment: `document.write` is bad because it prevents async loading of your JS.