# Can I include a JavaScript file inside another one at runtime?

Tags: javascript

I need to include a JavaScript file inside another one and use its functions at runtime. The file may exist in my server or in another one.

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-javascript-file-inside-javascript-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the answer of this question you can find it in the following :[Here](http://eslamsoliman.blogspot.com/2011/05/how-one-javascript-file-can-cause.html)

something like that visit the article to know more :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Function to allow one JavaScript file to be included by another.
// Copyright (C) 2006-08 www.cryer.co.uk
function IncludeJavaScript(jsFile)
{
  document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="'
    + jsFile + '"></scr' + 'ipt>'); 
}
</script>
```

and here are some links on stack overflow :

[One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842504/how-should-i-include-a-js-file-from-another-js-file)
[Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-javascript-file-inside-javascript-file)

Answer (score 8):

```
var sc=document.createElement('script');
sc.src="script.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(sc);
```

Use something like this

Answer (score 2):

With JQuery power do

```
$.ajax({
  url: yourURL,
  dataType: "script",
  async: false
});
```