# How to include a js file in another js file

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should I include a js file from another js file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842504/how-should-i-include-a-js-file-from-another-js-file)

In one of my js files, I need to use functions from other js file. How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to include both files in any page that uses your functions.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script myscript uses.js"></script>
```

The public functions in both files will be available to each other.

You *could* add a `<script>` element to the DOM in your script that are pointing to the dependencies - this will allow you to only include your javascript file in a page.

```
document.write("<script language='javascript' src='script myscript uses.js' />");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just load the dependent file after the source file - e.g. function in file a requires function in file b

```
<script src="b.js"/>
<script src="a.js"/>
```

If you want to dynamically load a script file then:

```
function loadScript(filename){
    // find the header section of the document
    var head=document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];

    // create a new script element in the document
    // store a reference to it
    var script=document.createElement('script')

    // attach the script to the head
    head.appendChild(script);

    // set the script type
    script.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")

    // set the script source, this will load the script
    script.setAttribute("src", filename)
}

loadScript("someScript.js");
```

Google uses this to import the adsense code into a page.

UPDATED

Comment: I believe that you need to attach your `script` element to the DOM for the source file to be fetched and loaded, i.e. do something like `document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);`

Answer (score 0):

Including both to the page in the right sequence:

```
<head>
   ...
   <script type="text/javascript" src="library.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts_that_use_library_functions.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add js files dynamically in your DOM, like this :

```
var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];         
var newScript = document.createElement('script');  
newScript.type = 'text/javascript';  
newScript.src = 'http://www.somedomain.com/somescript.js';  
headID.appendChild(newScript);
```